# Send Files as email attachment from Apex

Tags: apex, lightning, files

We have a requirement to send email with attachment. When a Opportunity stage is changed need to send a email to opportunity owner with attachments(Files added to a custom object).

This work fine when attachments are added in salesforce classic and email will be sent to with attachments. But when we 'Upload File' in Notes And Attachment in partner community or lightning attachments are not added to the email. Because in partner community or in lightning attachments are added as ContentDocumnet.

Can any help us to add attach ContentDocument file in attachment.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: You're correct that ContentDocuments are different than Attachments. Can you share the code you're using now? It shouldn't be difficult to extend the code to account for one or the other.